# Accounting database design question "accounts" and "transactions"

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

Option 1) user can have multiple "accounts" (eg payment, deposits, withdraws etc)

Option 2) user can only 1 single account, and transaction has types (payment, deposit, withdraw)

Both option will work just fine! They both can produce the same result! However option 1 uses more resources, but it's more flexible, option 1 is not flexible but uses less resources!

Comment: What exactly is the question? How can we help?

Comment: I can't decide which one to choose or how others do it? Althought I know the result come out the same.

Comment: if you know you'll have multiple types of accounts and they'll change over time, go for the more flexible solution. If not, and you're sure you'll only have these account types, go for option 2. I'd personally choose option 1, since the performance impact would not be huge.

Comment: Are you sure you've got these requirements right? I can't imagine any qualified accountant referring to a withdraw[al] as a type of account! It seems to me that you don't really know what you want yet so I don't think you are ready to design it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is the question ?

Option 1 is a piece of garbage, that no accountant can use, and no auditor will pass. payment, deposits, withdraws eta re transactions, not "accounts".  So what if it uses less resources.   SO do cave men.

Option 2  starts to look like an accounting system, with (a) accounts and (b) transactions against accounts, as expected in most developed countries.

So there is no choice.

Comment: Obviously none of the options describe the full set of accounting tables, 

User, account, account_balance, transaction, journal, journal_type  etc etc etc  

But rather the specific tables in question only.

Comment: @001.Well, I cannot answer re the details you have nto posted, I have answered re the details that you **have** posted.  The more detail you provide, the more detailed and considerate our answers can be.  Post your Data Model or DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Start from a journal table, that link to a chart of accounts table. In your journal table is where you will store fieldnames for transaction date, account code, description, amount. chart of account table is where you will store fieldnames like account code, account type (balance sheet or profit and loss),account status (active or inactive). For greater details on the accounting database schema, download derek liew's book on accounting database design.